# Changes to JSP not reflected when deployed to local engine

Tags: html, eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp, google-plugin-eclipse

Any changes to JSP in eclipse like removing css layouts, html tags in eclipse not reflecting when the google webapp is deployed on local test server.
What are the possible problems causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I found doing a shift-refresh in the browser does wonders. What you described is typical of browser caching and doesn't have anything to do with the local server.

Other than that nothing else comes to mind that would explain your problems.